# Existing javascript frameworks to handle session timeout warnings?

Tags: javascript, session, session-timeout

I have a need to do be able to show a user a message that there session is about to expire before expiring.  If the user does nothing the page then redirects to session expired page.  This need does not feel unusual.

So I am hoping some JavaScript library or framework could help with such a project.  My existing solution actually opens up a new window.  But now with iPads commonly being used, I am seeing solution that do some dynamic HTML to prompt the user on the current page.

I have existing code that can make and AJAX call to decide when a user sessions will expire.  (Maybe site is open in multiple tabs).  So I can handle the timing of when to show the message.

I am just hoping that there might be some common code to help create the UI for a timeout warning.

Technically, most of our pages are Java pages.  But with Javascript solution, the pages that is displaying should be less important.

I was hoping JQuery or YUI had something.  But I have not found it so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might consider is a plugin for "toast", the name meaning the message pops up as if from a toaster; see the following: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11998/what-is-a-toast-notification

For an actual jquery plugin there is the following: https://github.com/azcoov/jQuery-Toaster

Comment: Yes...That was very helpful. The demo for the jquery toast you have above did not work for me. But I found this jquery toast that seemed to work: https://github.com/akquinet/jquery-toastmessage-plugin